# Clicking on both menu which can be shown on image Main menu and Search box opens at same time? It should open one menu and closes other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, menu

[Image of menu how it looks when opening the both menus.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMxS1.png)

click on one by one to both menu, both menu displays rather than when i click on one menu closes other. How can i do that?

```
 $('.toggle-sm-nav, .js-toggle-sm-navigation').click(function(){

        // Change button
        $(this).children('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify icon-close-menu-cross2');
        $('.sm-searchboxc').find('i').removeClass('active');

        // Toggle menu on hamburger
        $('.navcontainer').toggle();
        $('.header-nav-container').toggleClass('brgropen');

        if( $('.header-nav-container').hasClass('brgropen') ){
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        } else {
            $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
        }
    });
        // Focus search field when opened
        $('.js-toggle-xs-search').on('click', function(){
            $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').trigger('touchstart');

        });
        $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').on('touchstart', function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').focus();
            }, 0);    
       });
```

HTML Code is shown below.

```
<div class="sm-navigation">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="sm-nav col-xs-1 col-sm-1 visible-sm">
                        <button class="btn btn-default js-toggle-sm-navigation toggle-sm-nav btn-sm" type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 logocontainer">
                        <div class="site-logo">

                            <div class="content"><a href="/"><img src="/_ui/responsive/theme-blue/images/abc.svg"></a></div></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="xs-nav col-xs-3 col-sm-3 visible-xs">
                        <button class="btn btn-default js-toggle-sm-navigation" type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="xs-store-finder col-xs-3 visible-xs ">
                        <a href="/store-finder">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon icon-store-locator"></span>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="xs-search col-xs-3 visible-xs">
                        <button class="btn btn-default js-toggle-xs-search toggle-xs-search btn-sm" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon icon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    <div class="searchboxc md-searchboxc col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <div class="site-search ui-front">
    <form id="search-form" name="search-form" method="get" class="search-form ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength" ng-submit="search.submit()" ng-controller="SearchController as search" action="/search/">
```

The image can be shown below.click on one by one to both menu, both menu displays rather than when i click on one menu closes other. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you nested your 'on-click search function "

> $('.js-toggle-xs-search').on('click', function(){

inside your navigation on-click function?

> $('.toggle-sm-nav, .js-toggle-sm-navigation').click(function(){

Comment: Actually this is not the problem, the problem is when click on main menu it opens and when click on search menu, the search bar opens in main menu,  as you can see in the image link which is given on the top. Any help would be highly appreciaated.

Comment: Can you provide a working code...
with jsfiddle or smth?

Comment: Its too much code to place on fiddle, i am missing some trick with the class, kindly advise me. It is more than 1 lac line code